# emulator-x86.exe has stopped working after lauching

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio in Windows 8.1 with 4 GB RAM; given 2 GB to virtual memory. But when ever I run the emulator I get the following:

> C:\Users\CSE\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Android_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
>   emulator: device fd:828
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>   emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
>   creating window 0 0 384 729
>   emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

The emulator starts and suddenly stops showing massage:

> emulator-x86.exe has stopped working

I have edited the current device & also created new AVD with resolution 800x600 and RAM 512 MB ( & less ) but nothing works. HMAX is installed.

Suggestions will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved in a laptop with Windows 10 + HAXM enabled, to run the default "Nexus 5 API 23 x86" Device.

My laptop has 2 video cards, the integrated Intel HD 3000 and a GeForce 525M.
On NVIDIA Control Panel, switch "Preferred graphics processor" to Auto-select or Integrated graphics.

The emulator doesn't work here when I set the NVIDIA GPU as preferred.

Comment: I hate Nvidia Optimus and mobile display adapters -_-

Answer (score 1):

Check this path
`C:\Users\Username.android\avd`. Edit the file `emulator-user` & set the `window.x = 0`, `window.y = 0`

Comment: I set window.x = 0 but then the avd could not be recognized. So, I created a new avd deleting the previous one but the new avd has no "emulator-user" config file.

Answer (score 0):

Create the hdpi virtual device like Nexus S 4.0 480x800 hdpi.

In AVD Manager, Select your device which is stopped. And click the edit in the right side of the wizard. It shows the options and features of your current device like ROM size, Internal and External Storage etc. 
Uncheck the Use Host GPU.

In that wizard select Show Advanced Settings -> Memory and Storage -> RAM: 764MB
VM heap: 32MB
Internal Storage: 200MB

Change these settings and restart your Android Studio